# how to get all the controls on the windows form page

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

> I have a windows forms; and there are several controls on it.
>   I want to have them in a foreach loop to call each control's Clear() method, to make it clear and re-initiliazed item.

How can I do it?**

> When I wath the formpage on debug-mode of Vs 2008, I see the "this" thus I can see all of them inside it..

.net version: 2.0

Comment: Which Control has a `.Clear()`-Method?

Comment: If you see it in the debugger, you should be able to use it in code, especially with the help of IntelliSense.

Comment: @ the NumberEntry whic is derived from text box control on our team project

Comment: @jv42 I know I can do it that way, but I am curious if I get them all in a loop to call Clear method, which is common for all objects in "this" form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could iterate through controls like this:

```
foreach (Control ctrl in this.Controls)
{
    if (ctrl is NumberEntry)
    {
        ((NumberEntry)ctrl).Clear();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You might have controls on controls on controls etc. So it might be a good idea to put Dmitry Erokhin's code in a recursive function:

```
private void ClearNumberEntries(ControlCollection controls)
{
    foreach (Control ctrl in controls)
    {
        if (ctrl is NumberEntry)
        {
            ((NumberEntry)ctrl).Clear();
        }
        //if you are sure a NumberEntry can never have child controls that could also be of type NumberEntry you can put this in an else in stead
        ClearNumberEntries(ctrl.Controls);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

for initializing controls again no need to clear each controls, just clear controls in form and call  InitializeComponent()

```
 private void InitializeControls()
        {
            this.Controls.Clear();
            InitializeComponent();
        }
```